# CloudFunctions.getHttpsCallable parameters

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

Since the version 0.2.0 `cloud_functions` for Flutter use `.getHttpsCallable()` instead of `.call()`. The new method is defined as:

```
/// @param functionName The name of the callable function being triggered.
/// @param parameters Parameters to be passed to the callable function.
HttpsCallable getHttpsCallable(
    {@required String functionName, Map<String, dynamic> parameters}) {
  return HttpsCallable._(this, functionName);
}
```

As we can see, the argument `parameters` is not used though declared and documented (I learned it the hard way while debugging the app.) So, one is expected to pass the parameters to the subsequent `.call()` on the callable object. What's the reason why the argument is declared for the new method at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's reads like a bug report directed at the creators of a particular piece of software.  Post issues about FlutterFire on its GitHub instead.  https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/FlutterFire.md

Answer (score 3):

Although I can't explain why it was designed this way, some people might find this post looking for help using the getHttpsCallable function. Here is an example calling a cloud function called addUser with two parameters, email and password. These parameters would normally be defined in another way such as via the text property of a TextController.

```
CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
                          functionName: "addUser",
                      ).call(
                          <String, dynamic>{
                            "email": "test@test.com",
                            "password": "Terrific password!"
                          },
                      );
```

Answer (score 2):

I also wondered why but it does make for cleaner code at least:

```
HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
  functionName: 'myFunction',
);

try {
  HttpsCallableResult response = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
    'firstParam': firstParam,
    'secondParam': secondParam,
  });
} catch (e) {
  // ...
}
```